# Below If else condition is not working in my script

Tags: eclipse, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btnSendMailCopy")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/article/nav/button[2]")).isDisplayed())
{     
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/article/nav/button[2]")).click();   
    System.out.println("clicked");
}
else if(driver.findElement(By.id("VendorCardHolderName")).isDisplayed())
{  
    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("VendorTinCardType")));
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("VISA");
    driver.findElement(By.id("VendorCardHolderName")).sendKeys("TestName");
```

Without using if else i was able to run the script successfully but when I want to run else part its showing the error as

> Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/section[1]/div/article/nav/button[2]"}

Comment: Looks like it fails to find the element in if condition `if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/article/nav/button[2]")).isDisplayed())`, but you mention that error rises in the else statement. Could it be that it does not find the `button[2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per code if first element is displayed then go for code in if, if that first element is not displayed then go for code in else.

now simple thing here is, if the first element is not displayed then sure we will receive no element exception right? so we need handle this by try/catch.

```
Boolean dd;

try{
 dd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/article/nav/button[2]")).isDisplayed();
}catch(Exception e){
 //you can print as element not displayed
}
```

then go for if condition

```
 if(dd==true){
  //do something
  }else{
 //do some thing else
 }
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Hello Murali,I tried above script but its throwing error in If condition as to create local variable/parameter/field for dd in if condition and when i didnt use Try/catch there was no error to create a variable for dd

Comment: hey sorry create Boolean dd as global and use it

Comment: Thanks!!! Murali..It worked..Now i am able to run the script with no issues.Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Try code as below:-

```
    Boolean dd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/article/nav/button[2]")).isDisplayed();

    if(dd==true)
    {     
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/article/nav/button[2]")).click();   
        System.out.println("clicked");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Element is not found");
    }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: A bit of explanation would help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   driver.findElement(By.id("btnSendMailCopy")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/article/nav/button[2]")).size()>0)
    {     
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/article/nav/button[2]")).click();   
        System.out.println("clicked");
    }
    else if(driver.findElements(By.id("VendorCardHolderName")).size()>0)
    {  
        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("VendorTinCardType")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("VISA");
        driver.findElement(By.id("VendorCardHolderName")).sendKeys("TestName");
}
```

It was failed due to that element you are checking at isDisplayed was not available. So to overcome that you have to write try/catch or the code I provide. They should work.